# What's wrong with this CAML query?

Tags: caml-query

The And block of Field3 is being ignored. It doesn't matter if the text matches or not. What's wrong here?

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
      <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Field2' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Something</Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
  <And>
    <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name='Field3' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Testing</Value>
    </Contains>
  </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Field8' Ascending='True' />
</OrderBy>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Counter">1</Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="ContentType" /><Value Type="Computed">test</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">aaa</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

It should be like this. Use [U2U caml builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I've had it work like this, nesting the Ands at the beginning

```
<Where>
  <And><And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
      <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Field2' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Something</Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
    <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name='Field3' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Testing</Value>
    </Contains>
  </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Field8' Ascending='True' />
</OrderBy>
```

Comment: Combining operators in CAML is something of a black art and something I find impossible to describe, even after writing (horrible) code that generates CAML I still can't describe effectively how the nesting works, but yes, it involves nesting all but the last clause for every second degree.

Comment: Black art is an understatement. Yes, It took me awhile to realize that they go at the beginning of the query.

Comment: If I was ever to make a query like this I would test and log with linq first, the dangers of making a query like this extremely slow are high. This query should be okay, it all depends on the amount of data the contains is sifting through, 1 contains is okay, 2 is iffy and 3+ you really need to balance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Camlex.NET. It takes care of the nesting when you use the Camlex.Query().WhereAll(expressions).ToString() method.

[Camlex.NET on Codeplex](http://camlex.codeplex.com/)